# Defining a different namespace inside a schema (WSDL)

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, wsdl, schema

I've been searching for an answer to this question but I can't find it anywhere. Wondering if someone could help me out.

I have a WSDL like this:

```
<ws:types>
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ww="http://ww"
             elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xs:element name="GenericNode">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="request">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="Message" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                <xs:element name="ServiceID" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</ws:types>
```

(Some of the names were changed because of confidentiality)

I am getting the following SoapUI message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GenericNode>
         <tem:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Message>anyType</tem:Message>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:ServiceID>anyType</tem:ServiceID>
         </tem:request>
      </tem:GenericNode>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My problem is, I don't want the elements "Message" and "ServiceID" to have namespace tem:. I want them to have namespace ww:.

How can I do that without changing the namespaces of anything else?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the target namespace of the schema. That is, replace

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" ...
```

by

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://ww" ...
```

Now to be sure, this doesn't necessarily get you `ww` as namespace *prefix*, but it'll result in `http://ww` being used as namespace *URI*.

The namespace prefix as such is insignificant in XML as long as it maps to the correct namespace URI and is used consistently within a document instance; it could be anything, such as `ns0`.